# google chrome extensions notifications with php file

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

I am creating a PHP site.

I created a Google Chrome Extension.

I want to know how to create a desktop notification when I create a new article.

I created the system.

I started with checking on the index if cookie's "newestA" value is the newest article.

Thats mean, when getting into the newest article, if you don't have the cookie, or you have cookie with another value, it's making a cookie and her value is the newest article.

How to do that every time I get into a site, like google, it checking if my cookie's value is the newset one, and if it false so it make a notification with a link to the article.

Thanks, Gil